# power bi report server developer license

Tags: power-bi-report-server

During installation of power bi report server if I choose developer edition instead of entering a license code is there a limitation  of capability  or there is no difference in working and performance of the report server

Answer (score 0):

I hope licensing should be same as SQL Server Developer edition.

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/01/21/test-the-latest-features-with-sql-server-2017-developer-edition/